# Two arrays gives third array with maximum values

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote code, but I don't know how to get maximum values after comparison between two arrays.

The program defines 2 fields of equal numbers of the same length, whereby the user initially defines the length of the field . After entering the elements, another field is created that will place a higher number in the first or second field in the same position in each position. Print in a row: elements of the 1st field of element 2 of the field fields of the new field.

Example:

```
If field1 = {2, 4, 32, 7} and field2 = {22, 1, 3, 2} then
field3 = {max (2.22), max (4.1), max 32.3), max (7.2)} = {22, 4, 32, 7}
```

Comment: Try formatting this question again. Here: [edit].

Comment: how about you post the effort you made the question & we will help you

Comment: If you are having trouble in formatting the code then refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: please post a [mcve].  We are not mind readers so cannot guess as to what you have written

Comment: `I wrote code` - show it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **PRINT** the field 3, than you can do this like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int ara1[n], ara2[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &ara1[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &ara2[i]);
    }
    printf("{");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("max(%d.%d)", ara1[i], ara2[i]);
        if(i != n-1) printf(",");
    }
    printf("}");

}
```